# How do I make a photo Dashboard list activity?

Tags: android, listview

One of the things I love is the new Android Favorites Contact screen:

[image]

I want to implement something similar in my app, but I don't know how do I make a list activity show two items per row instead of just one. If anyone has any code to do something similar, it would be awesome.

Comment: Have a look at [Hello GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).

Comment: Thanks Alex- Got it working- but for those of you following on from this afterwards- the graphical layout editor in eclipse still doesn't display the views correctly- so you will have to keep building to phone to see what that layout looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I believe the code for that screen is actually available in [AOSP](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts) :)

The part you might be interested in studying is the [ContactTileListFragment](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/src/com/android/contacts/list/ContactTileListFragment.java)
and [ContactTileAdapter](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/src/com/android/contacts/list/ContactTileAdapter.java) code. In short, each row in the `ListView` is composed from a configurable number of "tiles" (basically `FrameLayouts` containing views inflated from the resource).

Comment: Thanks for this- I personally found it easier to use Grid View with 2 layouts.  But this is really helpful ( although I don't think I am at the level to fully understand the AOSP code just yet( at least not in a day)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinions listView with two items per row can make this.